# move command unable to remove file

Tags: shell-script, centos, terminal, mv

I'm trying to move a set of 60GB files from one folder to another using

```
mv -v /home/mnt1/Daily_IMSI_Report/* /mnt2/Archive_1/Daily_IMSI_Report/
```

But the command is not executing after copying only one file. I think it is not able to remove the file after copying. This is the output I'm getting in the terminal with the running state:

```
copied '/home/mnt1/Daily_IMSI_Report/IMSI_exp_20220323.csv.gz' -> '/mnt2/Archive_1/Daily_IMSI_Report/IMSI_exp_20220323.csv.gz'
```

Every time I stop and run the command, one more file gets copied after taking confirmation for overwriting. Both the folders have `777` rights.

```
type mv
mv is aliased to `mv -i'
```

The filesystems are mounted using NFS4 on CentOS.

Observing the similar situation with `cp` command, I think the `*` wildcard operator is not able to continue to the next file after completing the first copy operation.

What would be causing the issue here?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the output of `type mv`. Also, tell us what filesystems the source and destination directories are on.

Comment: Do you get any error messages? If so, please [edit] your question to include them

Comment: `I think the * wildcard operator is not able to continue to the next file after completing the first copy operation` → note this isn't really how glob characters like `*` work; the `*` gets expanded to the files by the shell first, and then the result is passed to the program (`mv` in this case), which has no way of seeing if a `*` was used or if you typed it all manually. You can test if `*` matches what you expect with just `ls /home/mnt1/Daily_IMSI_Report/*`.

Comment: @roaima no I'm not getting any error message. The cursor just keeps blinking after copying the first file. I was able to copy one by one and then remove the copied files one by one from the source directory.

Comment: What does `ls -d /home/mnt1/Daily_IMSI_Report/*` return? It should be the set of files to move.

Comment: "_The cursor just keeps blinking after copying the first file_" how big are these files? Could it be that the move operation was still in progress, particularly if `/home/mnt1/Daily_IMSI_Report` and `/mnt2/Archive_1/Daily_IMSI_Report` are on different NFS filesystems.

Comment: `ls -d /home/mnt1/Daily_IMSI_Report/*` returns all the files list like `/home/mnt1/Daily_IMSI_Report/IMSI_exp_20220422.csv.gz` The files are 60G per and the manual operation of copying and deleting was quite fast

Comment: Well yes, `ls` is just listing the files, but you are transferring multiple sets of 60G files over  NFS. That can take anything from minutes up to several hours depending on your NFS setup. Are you sure there is a problem here?

Comment: 60G per? No matter what your backing store that's going to take a measurable time

Comment: But it's quite fast if I do it for files individually